# Looking for a translation コミカライズ

Tags: translation

Please, help me to understand the word コミカライズ. 
It was in phrase 衝撃のコミカライズ

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is "comicalize", or to turn into a comic/manga.

[According to hatena.jp:](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/keyword/%A5%B3%A5%DF%A5%AB%A5%E9%A5%A4%A5%BA)

> - 小説、アニメ、ゲーム、映画、ドラマなどをマンガ化すること。
> - 小説化を意味する「ノベライズ」から派生した和製英語。